# Is Foundation Responsive?

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to find a CSS framework that is fully responsive and I believe Foundation is, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foundation will work perfect as a CSS framework, I would definitely go with that.